# Citus: pg_stat_all_tables is empty

Tags: metadata, citus

I need to get table usage info.
But if I run the select * from pg_stat_all_tables I see zero or null values along citus tables.

The same result on coordinator and worker node.

How can I get the tuple usage, vaccum time execution at the Citus tables?

Citus version is 11.1.5.

Thanks for help.

I expect that query select * from pg_stat_all_tables get non zero cells result like if I run it on the Postgres node.

actual:
"relid" "schemaname"    "relname"   "seq_scan"  "seq_tup_read"  "idx_scan"  "idx_tup_fetch" "n_tup_ins" "n_tup_upd" "n_tup_del" "n_tup_hot_upd" "n_live_tup"    "n_dead_tup"    "n_mod_since_analyze"   "n_ins_since_vacuum"    "last_vacuum"   "last_autovacuum"   "last_analyze"  "last_autoanalyze"  "vacuum_count"  "autovacuum_count"  "analyze_count" "autoanalyze_count"
"****"  "***"   "****"  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0                   0   0   0   0

expect: non zero/null result

Answer (score 1):

Queries hit on shards as Citus tables are distributed. (e.g. not on `dist` but `dist_1233`) Currently we do not have a user friendly function to see those stats for a distributed table but as a workaround you can run below query to fetch stats on each shard for the table.

`SELECT * FROM run_command_on_shards('xx', 'select row(pgstats.*) from pg_stat_all_tables pgstats where relname like ''%s'';');`

Comment: This is helpful. At first I was thinking I can create a view looking similar to pg_stat_all_tables showing the sum of the shard counters, however, I noticed the shards have their counters reset at times I don't understand yet. Would be really helpful if you can share more of your thoughts and plans regarding this.